# How to reversibly escape a URL in Ruby so that it can be saved to the file system

Tags: ruby, string, file

The use-case example is saving the contents of `http://example.com` as a filename on your computer, but with the unsafe characters (i.e. `:` and `/`) escaped.

The classic way is to use a regex to strip all non-alphanumeric-dash-underscore characters out, but then that makes it impossible to reverse the filename into a URL. Is there a way, possibly a combination of `CGI.escape` and another filter, to sanitize the filename for both Windows and *nix? Even if the tradeoff is a much longer filename?

edit:

Example with `CGI.escape`

```
 CGI.escape 'http://www.example.com/Hey/whatsup/1 2 3.html#hash'
 #=> "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2FHey%2Fwhatsup%2F1+2+3.html%23hash"
```

A couple things...are `%` signs completely safe as file characters? Unfortunately, `CGI.escape` doesn't convert spaces in a malformed URL to `%20` on the first pass, so I suppose any translation method would require changing all spaces to `+` with a `gsub` and *then* applying `CGI.escape`

Comment: how about url-encoding the url? convert characters to `%XX`.

Comment: I'll add an example to the question to clarify where things stand...but I didn't know for sure if % signs were safe across major operating systems

Comment: This is very challenging (impossible) task given file-name length limitations.

Comment: It's only impossible if you want to deal with the most extreme edge cases. However, it shouldn't be impossible to come up with a function (I was hoping it was somewhere in stdlib but apparently not) that does the translation and leaves it up to the client to deal with file-length limitations. For example, the client may decide to store the URLs in corresponding subdirectories:

Comment: write your own url-escaping function and use something else instead of `%`. say, an underscore.

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways is by "hashing" the filename. For example, the URL for this question is: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234870/how-to-reversibly-escape-a-url-in-ruby-so-that-it-can-be-saved-to-the-file-syste`. You could use the Ruby standard library's `digest/md5` library to hash the name. Simple and elegant.

```
require "digest/md5"

foldername = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234870/how-to-reversibly-escape-a-url-in-ruby-so-that-it-can-be-saved-to-the-file-syste"
hashed_name = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(foldername) # => "5045cccd83a8d4d5c4fc01f7b4d8c502"
```

The corollary for this scheme would be that MD5 hashing is used to validate the authenticity/completeness of downloads since for all practical purposes, the MD5 digest of the string always returns the same hex-string.

However, I won't call this "reversible". You need to have a custom way to look up the URLs for each of the hashes that get generated. May be, a `.yml` file with that data.

---

update: As [@the Tin Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128421/the-tin-man) suggests, a simple SQLite db would be much better than a `.yml` file when there are a large number of files that need storing.

Comment: I'd recommend using MD5 also. Using a YAML file isn't going to be maintainable or scalable. Instead, a small SQLite DB would be very good. It'd run circles around YAML because it allows an index and random access. The downside is the filenames are lost if the DB gets trashed or deleted.

Comment: @theTinMan Did you just shoot down an idea in the name of scalability and then suggest sqlite as an alternative?  Any on-disk file format should do as long as you keep your records in order (your hash values are basically non-sequential serial numbers).  Worst-case, you might have to segment your reverse lookup files.

Comment: MD5-hashing is definitely a solution for some use cases. However, in some particular use cases, it's helpful to have the filename be recognizable (despite all the % signs)...with a hashing function, regardless of its reversibility, it becomes impossible to eyeball.

Comment: YAML isn't going to be scalable because the file has to be parsed and rewritten each time it's modified, in its entirety. The overhead of doing that will be higher than an equivalent on-disk SQLite DB, plus SQLite will be faster for lookups because it doesn't have to be loaded and parsed. For a few files on disk it'd be a wash. For thousands, there'd be no comparison. This is used inside commercial apps that have to track multi-thousands of files on disk. Using something like [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html) would make it a trivial task.

Comment: @Zando You didn't say that was a requirement and frankly, that's not feasible for so many reasons (filename length, illegal characters, etc)

Comment: @theTinMan You think that sqlite databases don't have to be loaded and parsed to be used??

Comment: @IronSavior ...right, but the actual question is just looking for a method or implementation...this hypothetical method would only be in charge of translating between URL and filename (and in reverse)...it has no knowledge or concern with what other constrains the hypothetical file system may impose.

Answer (score 2):

here is how I would do it (adjust the regular expression as needed):

```
url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234870/how-to-reversibly-escape-a-url-in-ruby-so-that-it-can-be-saved-to-the-file-syste"
filename = url.each_char.map {|x|
  x.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9-]/) ? x : "_#{x.unpack('H*')[0]}"
}.join
```

EDIT:

if the length of the resulting file name is a concern then I would store the files in sub-directories with the same names as the url path segments.